# Cakephp 2.0.4 ACL error

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

I'm getting below error with ACL.

```
Warning (512): AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aro node identified by "Array
(
    [Aro0.model] => Group
    [Aro0.foreign_key] => 1
)
" [CORE/Cake/Model/AclNode.php, line 179]
Warning (512): DbAcl::check() - Failed ARO/ACO node lookup in permissions check.  Node references:
Aro: Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [username] => hybmg57
            [created] => 2012-02-08 22:20:23
            [welcome] => 
            [group_id] => 1
            [options] => a:8:{i:0;s:8:"locality";i:1;s:8:"postcode";i:2;s:13:"dwelling_type";i:3;s:13:"typical_value";i:4;s:3:"dsr";i:5;s:11:"dsr_summary";i:6;s:5:"yield";i:7;s:2:"sr";}
        )

)

Aco: controllers/Users/my_favourite_suburbs [CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/AclComponent.php, line 303]
```

Is there something I could change to get this working? I followed example of Cookbook in Cake's site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error caused by missing permissions in your ACL. Make sure that you've assigned permissions for `Group 1` to `controllers` -> `Users` -> `my_favourite_suburbs`. Have a look at the `acos`, `aros` and `acos_aros` tables.

Please note that the `acos` and `aros` tables are trees and the values for `lft` and `rght` must be set properly.

Answer (score 0):

I was also Facing the same error.but when i added

```
App::uses('AclComponent', 'Controller/Component');
```

in the User model,and now it working.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: sorry..forget to do dat